# How to mark row as header?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I googled, but did not found any solution for simple question. How to mark row as header with `xlsxwriter` lib?

```
cell_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'align': 'center', 'border': 2})
```

Ok. I can colorize it, but I have issue with sorting digits in excel, because Excel do not understand where data and where is header.

[image]

The header on screenshot have format `common`, the digits - number. But excel suggest to sort me data by the alphabet, not as numbers.

With follow code Excel suggest me to "recover document":

```
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(excel_filename)
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    wrap = workbook.add_format({'text_wrap': True})
    worksheet.add_table('A1:W1', {'header_row': True}) # If remove it all OK, but no header works
    wrap_format_digit = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00'})

    row = 0
    col = 0

    cell_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'align': 'center', 'border': 2})
```

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean by "mark row as header"? you know how to style, what else is missing for "marking" the row as header?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is probably header_row

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_tables.html

```py
worksheet.add_table('B4:F7', {'header_row': true})
```

Comment: not working. I have add explanation to start topic. Maybe there is way to another way to do it?